# C# & SQL Server : users cannot connect remotely

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can connect locally to my login/password database but remote users cannot.

The error following as

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.
>   When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the
>   fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
>   connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I can perfectly go into this program, but when testing on another's location it throws this error.

Here is my login code.

As well

1. My firewall is not the problem, I have turned it off and it still does not work. I then as well added rules to allow the UDP and TCP 1433 and 1434 ports in.
2. The name is correct. It  connects perfectly to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2015.
3. It connects as well fine to Visual Studio 2015.
4. SQL Server Browser service is running.
5. Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is allowing remote connections.

Here is the code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class loginpage : Form
    {
        public loginpage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Connection String
        string cs = @"Data Source=MS-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=break;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=False;Context Connection=False;MultiSubnetFailover=False;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=False";
        //btn_Submit Click event

        public sealed class SecurePasswordHasher
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Size of salt
            /// </summary>
            private const int SaltSize = 16;

            /// <summary>
            /// Size of hash
            /// </summary>
            private const int HashSize = 20;

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a hash from a password
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="password">the password</param>
            /// <param name="iterations">number of iterations</param>
            /// <returns>the hash</returns>
            public static string Hash(string password, int iterations)
            {
                //create salt
                byte[] salt;
                new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[SaltSize]);

                //create hash
                var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
                var hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(HashSize);

                //combine salt and hash
                var hashBytes = new byte[SaltSize + HashSize];
                Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, SaltSize);
                Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, SaltSize, HashSize);

                //convert to base64
                var base64Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

                //format hash with extra information
                return string.Format("$MYHASH$V1${0}${1}", iterations, base64Hash);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Creates a hash from a password with 10000 iterations
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="password">the password</param>
            /// <returns>the hash</returns>
            public static string Hash(string password)
            {
                return Hash(password, 10000);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Check if hash is supported
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="hashString">the hash</param>
            /// <returns>is supported?</returns>
            public static bool IsHashSupported(string hashString)
            {
                return hashString.Contains("$MYHASH$V1$");
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// verify a password against a hash
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="password">the password</param>
            /// <param name="hashedPassword">the hash</param>
            /// <returns>could be verified?</returns>
            public static bool Verify(string password, string hashedPassword)
            {
                //check hash
                if (!IsHashSupported(hashedPassword))
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException("The hashtype is not supported");
                }

                //extract iteration and Base64 string
                var splittedHashString = hashedPassword.Replace("$MYHASH$V1$", "").Split('$');
                var iterations = int.Parse(splittedHashString[0]);
                var base64Hash = splittedHashString[1];

                //get hashbytes
                var hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Hash);

                //get salt
                var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
                Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, SaltSize);

                //create hash with given salt
                var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
                byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(HashSize);

                //get result
                for (var i = 0; i < HashSize; i++)
                {
                    if (hashBytes[i + SaltSize] != hash[i])
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Hash
            var hash = SecurePasswordHasher.Hash("password");

            //Verify
            var result = SecurePasswordHasher.Verify("password", hash);

            if (txtUsername.Text == "" || txt_Password.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please provide a Username and Password");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                //Create SqlConnection
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tabl_login where UserName = @username and Password = @password", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txt_Password.Text);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapt.Fill(ds);

                con.Close();

                int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

                //If count is equal to 1, than show frmMain form
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful!");

                    Form1 objFrmMain = new Form1();
                    this.Hide();
                    objFrmMain.ShowDialog();
                    this.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Login Failed!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the IP for it?

Comment: try in cmd ```ping MS-LAPTOP```

Comment: also try to connect using ip,port => ip,1434

Comment: Make sure you have sql browser service enabled, also the tcpip protocol enabled in the sql configuration tool.